# How to make an Excel file a VB.NET resource for dataGridview form?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I’m learning VB.NET, so please forgive my ignorance...

I’m using a dataGridView form to display an Excel file (.xls) as a help file. I use Excel format because it formats very well, can be updated in Excel, and looks great in the dataGridView form...much easier and better than a standard text file.

But even though I can access the file from disk ("C:\DTC.XLS”), I want to place the file inside the VB app itself as a resource. I haven’t been able to do this successfully. I dragged the file into Solution Explorer > My Project > Resources. It shows up as “DTC” under files.

In my code, if I replace the file path (‘C:\DTC.XLS') with the resource handle (My.Resources.DTC), I get an exception: “ System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only.’ ”

I’m ok with “read-only”...it’s just a help file. How can I get the dataGridView form to open this resource without exception?

My routine:

```
Private Sub DTCinfo(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DTCdataGridView_button.Click

    If DTCdataGridView_button.Text = "CLOSE Info" Then
        DataGridView1.Hide()
        DTCdataGridView_button.Text = "DTC Info"
        DTCdataGridView_button.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark

    Else
        DTCdataGridView_button.Text = "CLOSE Info"
        DTCdataGridView_button.BackColor = Color.Red

        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

        ' ***** THE FOLLOWING LINE WORKS OK WITH THIS SUBROUTINE:
        ' MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\DTC.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")

        ' ***** THE FOLLOWING LINE DOES NOT WORK WITH THIS SUBROUTINE (GENERATES AN EXCEPTION):
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=My.Resources.DTC;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")

        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
        DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
        DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.[True]

        AutoSizeColumnsMode = True
        AutoSizeRowsMode = True
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).AutoSizeMode = False

        DataGridView1.Columns(0).Width = 50
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).Width = 200
        DataGridView1.Columns(3).Width = 150

        DataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells

        With DataGridView1
            .RowHeadersVisible = False
            .Columns(0).HeaderText = "DTC"
            .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Test Mode"
            .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Description"
            .Columns(3).HeaderText = "Action"
        End With

        MyConnection.Close()
        DataGridView1.Show()

    End If

End Sub
```

I found another example of how to do this online. It's simpler to read and easier to understand, but I still get the same exception: "Cannot update: the database or object is read only." How to fix?

```
    ' here's another test....
Sub testDataGridView()

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ' Note, you should use My.Settings rather than My.Resources for storing the data source
    '        Dim connectionString As String =
    '            $"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={My.Settings.gizmotest};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    Dim connectionString As String =
        $"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={My.Resources.DTC};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    ' Note, you should use import statements for these objects e.g.
    ' Place this as the first line in the code file
    ' Imports System.Data.OleDb

    Using cn As New OleDbConnection With {.connectionString = connectionString}
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn, .CommandText = "select * from [Sheet1$]"}
            Try
                cn.Open()
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, seems that the DataGridView form won't work with a read-only source...or at least it won't if it's using the Excel input format...true? And I guess a resource can only be read-only...I guess? I couldn't figure this all out definitively, but it's my best guess...

So I created a temporary file on disk when opening the form, copied the resource to the file, opened the file in the DataGridView form, then closed and deleted the file. Voila! Works. Seems a bit kludgy to me, but hey, it works, looks good, so now on to bigger things....